# Jest implementation is executed but function is never called

Tags: javascript, jestjs

im new to jest and encountered something strange:

I got this test:

```
let mockedLogger = require('../util/testLogger');
jest.mock('../../handler/util/winstonLogHandler', () => {
    return {
        getLogger: function() {
            return mockedLogger;
        },
    };
});

const sendMock = jest
    .fn()
    .mockImplementationOnce(() => {
        return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
            resolve('something');
        });
    })
    .mockImplementationOnce(() => {
        return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
            reject('some error');
        });
    });
const message = {
    channel: {
        send: sendMock,
    },
};

const ping = require('../.././commands/util/ping');

describe('Testing the ping command', () => {
    test('it should have properties', () => {
        expect(ping.name).not.toBe(undefined);
        expect(ping.name).not.toBe(undefined);
        expect(ping.name).not.toBe(undefined);
    });
    describe('it should execute', () => {
        test('and send a message', () => {
            ping.execute(null, message);
            expect(sendMock).toBeCalled();
        });
        test('or log an error', () => {
            ping.execute(null, message);
            expect(mockedLogger.error).toBeCalledWith(`Ping: Error sending message: some error`);
        });
    });
});
```

testLogger:

```
const errorLogMock = jest
    .fn()
    .mockImplementation((log) => console.error(log))
    .mockName('errorLog');

module.exports = {
    error: errorLogMock,
};
```

for this module:

```
const winstonLogHandler = require('../../handler/util/winstonLogHandler');
const logger = winstonLogHandler.getLogger();

module.exports = {
    name: 'ping',
    description: 'pong!',
    disabled: false,
    requireDB: false,
    execute(client, message) {
        message.channel.send('pong!').catch(error => {
            logger.error(`Ping: Error sending message: ${error}`);
        });
    },
};
```

Now if I execute the test I get the Error that my logError Mock function was never called. Although in the console I see that the implementation was executed. So hows it possible for the implementation to be executed if the function was never called? Do I miss something?

Comment: Is any of the code you're testing async? If so you probably need to wait for it using async/await or manually returning a Promise in your tests.

Comment: Yes the Promises i manually returned in the implementation. Changing the tests to wait for all Promises to finish execution before checking the mock was the solution! Thanks a lot for the hint!

Comment: Cool, you can add it as your answer to help other users with this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

changing the test to:

```
describe('Testing the ping command', () => {
    test('it should have properties', () => {
        expect(ping.name).not.toBe(undefined);
        expect(ping.name).not.toBe(undefined);
        expect(ping.name).not.toBe(undefined);
    });
    describe('it should execute', () => {
        test('and send a message', () => {
            await ping.execute(null, message);
            expect(sendMock).toBeCalled();
        });
        test('or log an error', () => {
            await ping.execute(null, message);
            expect(mockedLogger.error).toBeCalledWith(`Ping: Error sending message: some error`);
        });
    });
});
```

solved the problem. Jest had no function call because the async code wasnt finished executing.